# Renaming Log Files Program [Beginner]

Tags: java, file, logging, directory, each

I would like to make a simple eclipse/java program which goes through a folder with many log files and renames each log file based on strings of text found inside the log file.

The log files are all text files, but are named .log.

Here is a screenshot of the folder containing the log files:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of an individual log file. In this case, I would like this log file to be renamed "EFT Daily Activity Report," which shows up in each line.

[image]

The problem is I don't know how to go through folders in eclipse/java to access each of the files.

EDIT: Why doesn't this work? Am I missing something with the directory? Sorry, I'm new to local directories in java :)

[image]

Comment: With Java  you can use [`Files.list()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-) to list all the files in a directory.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I don't think I know how to give it a local directory right. I've attached another screenshot of this.

Comment: `Files.list()` takes a `Path` object as an argument.  You can't just pass in the text of a path like you are trying to do, and even if it did, you would still need to pass in a `String`, by enclosing the path in quotation marks: "This is a string in Java".

Comment: How would you pass in a Path as an object? I've passed in URL's to my programs before, but never a local file directory like this. Sorry about that, I'm completely new to passing in local files and directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the following tutorial for File:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/file.html
If I understand your question correctly, the last example should be what you are looking for.